# Passing the const-qualified object to the 'std::move'

Tags: c++, move-semantics, static-code-analysis, pvs-studio

By doing some code analysis in *PVS-Studio*, it gave me some warning messages.

I have the following statement in a header file:

```
constexpr int MIN_ALLOWED_Y { 0 };
```

And in a source file:

```
std::make_pair<const int, const int>( std::move( MIN_ALLOWED_Y ), std::move( MAX_ALLOWED_Y ) )
```

In the above expression, I used `std::move` to cast `MIN_ALLOWED_Y` to an xvalue because I thought `std::make_pair` only accepts rvalues;

```
// from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair

template< class T1, class T2 >
constexpr std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

But I get warning messages like:

```
V833 Passing the const-qualified object 'MIN_ALLOWED_Y' to the 'std::move' function disables move semantics.
```

Is this a valid warning? If so then what should I do? Should I remove the `std::move` (maybe it's redundant in this case?)?

A better question would be where not to use `std::move`?

Comment: So your code does `std::move(MIN_ALLOWED_Y)` somewhere?  Why would it do that, is it due to some generic template code which isn't aware MIN_ALLOWED_Y is a simple integer?

Comment: @John Zwinck Yes. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
std::make_pair<const int, const int>( std::move( MIN_ALLOWED_Y ), std::move( MAX_ALLOWED_Y ) )
```

Is overly complicated.  Not only are the `move`s pointless as PVS Studio told you, but using `make_pair` when explicitly specifying the types is pointless.  You can simplify to:

```
std::pair<const int, const int>( MIN_ALLOWED_Y, MAX_ALLOWED_Y )
```

Which does the same thing without excess ceremony.

Comment: I wonder if those two `const`s are even needed.  Or maybe the type should be `const std::pair<int, int>`.  I suppose that's more of a question for the OP though.

Comment: I'm confused about `make_pair`'s behavior. Isn't `MIN_ALLOWED_Y` an **lvalue**?? How are `make_pair`'s rvalue reference parameters able to bind to an lvalue?

Comment: @digito_evo: You don't need `make_pair` at all, and let's keep it to one question per question please.

Comment: @digito_evo In the prototype of `make_pair` you looked at, the `&&` are "forwarding references", not rvalue references.

Comment: That's the reason I used `std::move`. I thought I have to pass rvalues in order for make_pair to work.

Comment: No, you don't have to use rvalues, and you aren't benefitting from make_pair anyway, since you're passing explicit template type parameters.

Comment: @John Zwinck Thanks. And BTW, switching to `std::pair` won't have any performance downsides, right?

Comment: Right, the compiler is more than smart enough to optimize both to the same thing.  In fact, `make_pair` is less direct, so you might wonder if using `pair` directly would be faster...but they'll be the same if you have optimization enabled at build time.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you wrote `std::move(MIN_ALLOWED_Y)` somewhere and you got a warning about it from a static analyzer.  Yes, I would remove the `std::move` because it doesn't make any sense to move a constant somewhere else.

Move semantics are for moving around C++ objects where it might impossible or expensive to copy the data/resources contained in the object.  The object that was the source of the data in the move operation is possibly changed by the move, but it's impossible for your constant to change.